# JS getting width not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, im having some issues with my web; I've got a responsive image slider that works properly if I give him a numeric value, so I made a JS to get this value when i load the web.
This is the js :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.item').css({
            'width': w + 'px'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that it gets the value but dont work as intended.

Here is an img of how it works with the numeric value on css :

[image: working as intended]
And this is what it does when it gets the value with the js.

[image: Not working properly.]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. Im using iosslider, cant put the web cause of permissions.

Comment: What the hell is valor?

Comment: I believe some more code is needed to debug! A [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is preferable.

Comment: sorry language editted

Comment: Ok comming more just a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the width of the image on `document.ready` may give unfavourabe results, try the width calculation on `windows load event` or if feasible to add a vendor JS use [`images loaded plugin`](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) which will watch images load to perfection.

To be more specific,

```
$('.item img').on('load',function(){
    //width calculation here
});
```

Comment: Not working, but probably cause of my mistakes, I guess its a little bit too much for me, Thanks anyway.